# How to run Kotlin script that uses another Kotlin file?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin Script `kotlin-experiment/Play.kts`

```
import experiment.*

println(sum(2, 2))
```

Kotlin Library `kotlin-experiment/Play.kts`

```
package experiment

fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
```

The compile and run command:

```
kotlinc -script Play.kts
```

produces an error:

```
Play.kts:3:9: error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
...
println(sum(2, 2))
        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Kotlin script does not support this functionality out of the box.

By using Kscript you get this and other nice features
https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript